# NodeJS - object of an object is undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to access a JSON object but I'm getting errors while accessing the object id. Could you please go through the code and let me know the mistake I'm making.

When I try to `console.log(obj.id);`  it says `undefined`

Here is the code:

```
  var orderidfirstuser = fs.readFileSync(`orderids/${orderid}.json`,'utf-8');
  var obj = JSON.parse(orderidfirstuser);
  obj.id = (obj.id);
  console.log(obj.id);
  obj.delivered = (obj.delivered);
  obj.title = (obj.title);
  obj.is_replacement = (obj.is_replacement);
  obj.paid_at = (obj.paid_at);
```

Comment: What should you get instead of `undefined` then?

Comment: What does `orderidfirstuser` look like?

Comment: orderidfirstuser  looks like this https://pastebin.com/raw/e6BafBiW

Comment: what do you get when you `console.log(orderidfirstuser.id)` ?

Comment: @JDunken I get undefined

Comment: Just tried [here](https://repl.it/repls/DelightfulScientificSubweb) with your example JSON from PasteBin, it works as intended. I suppose there's an issue with the argument you pass to `fs.readFileSync`. As a side note, you can replace `fs.readFile` + `JSON.parse` with a single `require` call.

Comment: i think u should use a callback func inside `readFileSync` and put ur codes inside there

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I was saving the unparsed object. That's why when I tried to read it caused this issue.